# Theano: ImportError: cannot import name raise_from

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, nvidia

I am trying to test out Theano on the new TX1.
I've installed by following the installation instruction.

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-dev python-pip python-nose g++ libblas-dev git
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --user
```

When I try to import theano in python, I get the following error message.

> ImportError: cannot import name raise_from

Is there anything wrong with my installation procedure?
Thanks.

Comment: Try this pip install --upgrade six

Comment: or pip3 install --upgrade six if your trying to use python3